# Working out a percentage from a array of numbers

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

I need to change the opacity of a li depending on the value (Which is set in the html).

So, here is an example of the html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="test">3</li>
    <li class="test">23</li>
    <li class="test">6</li>
    <li class="test">9</li>
    <li class="test">11</li>
    <li class="test">16</li>
    <li class="test">19</li>
</ul>
```

So, the highest value (23) would have an opacity of 100% while the next highest (19) would have the a lower percentage and so on.

The lowest value should be 10%.

I can do all of the JavaScript I'm just struggling with the calculation. Does any one have an idea how this could be worked out?

Comment: what opacity is the lowest value going to have? 50%? 20%? 0%? it makes a bit of a difference on the math.

Comment: Good point @zzzzBov the lowest would be 10% I guess. So its still visible.

Comment: jQuery might help simplify...

Comment: @Sidharth Mudgal The javascript is not the problem. Its the calculation. I don't see how jQuery will help me. Anyway, I already have jQuery included.

Comment: @CharliePrynn: So your numbers can vary; you want the highest number in any set to give you 100% and the lowest to always give you 10% and to scale the remaining numbers in that interval?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the highest opacity is 100% and the lowest is 10%, then here's what you want:

1. Determine the maximum value. Call it max.
2. Determine the minimum value. Call it min.
3. To each value, assign opacity `(10 + ((value - min) / (max - min)) * 90)` percent.

More generally, if the highest opacity is `X` and the lowest is `Y`, then the formula is `(Y + ((value - min) / (max - min)) * (X - Y))`.

Answer (score 3):

This is the formula:

```
percentage = 10 + (number - min)/(max - min)*90
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the minimum and maximum, then you can calculate the opacity as:

```
0.1 + 0.9 * (value - min) / (max - min)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/FBTBw/

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and solved it this way:

```
Array.prototype.toPercentage = function() {
  var arr = this
  return arr.map(function(d, i) {
    return (100 * d / arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)) | 0;
})}
```

Usage:
Given an Array, calculate the percentage of each element in the array.

```
var nums = [23, 3, 19, 16, 10, 15]
// the percentage
var numsPercent = nums.toPercentage()
```

Comment: to calculate total sum you use `reduce` - i agree. but why inside `map`? imagine an array of thousands of elements - it will be `n` loops inside `n` loops

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine a simple way of doing it. Lets say you want to style everything from 20% to 100% opacity (you could later change this to be determined by function arguments, but lets keep it simple for now). The first goal is to get the max and min value from the list:

```
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].children;
var min = Infinity, max = -Infinity;

for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   var val = parseInt(list[i].innerText, 10);
   min = Math.min(min, val);
   max = Math.max(max, val);
}
```

Now, you should just linearly scale the opacity value of each, like so -

```
var min_opacity = 20, max_opacity = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var val = parseInt(list[i].innerText, 10);
  list[i].style.opacity = (min_opacity + ((val - min) / (max - min)) * (max_opacity - min_opacity)  + "%";
}
```

To expand a bit on the math: most of the legwork here is getting a number on the interval of [0,1], where 0 represents the lowest value and 1 the highest. "(val - min) / (max - min)" performs this scaling: no number will be greater than "max - min" once min has been subtracted from it, and never less than zero once min has been subtracted from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const percentage = () => {
    let arr = [50, 3, 11.5, 25, 10, 15] 
    return arr.map((number) => ((number) / (50) * 100).toFixed())
  }
```

```
50 highest value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert:

- This: `[3, 23, 6, 9, 11, 16, 19]`
- To: `[2.022256449752507e-7, 98.1128445612884, 0.000004061810658965839, 0.00008158364796565559, 0.0006028261515736386, 0.08946733354469237, 1.7969994313310655]` (all sum 100%)

with `Math.exp` ([Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function):

```js
const data = [3, 23, 6, 9, 11, 16, 19]
const sumExp = data.reduce((a, b) => a + Math.exp(b), 0)
const percents = data.map(x => (Math.exp(x) / sumExp) * 100)
```

If you want to display it pretty to render the values on the screen, you can use `Intl.NumberFormat`:

- To: `['0%', '98.11%', '0%', '0%', '0%', '0.09%', '1.8%']`

```js
const data = [3, 23, 6, 9, 11, 16, 19]
const { format } = Intl.NumberFormat('en', { 
   style: 'percent',
   maximumFractionDigits: 2
})
const sumExp = data.reduce((a, b) => a + Math.exp(b), 0)
const percents = data.map(x => format(Math.exp(x) / sumExp))
```

Answer (score -1):

Percentage_value = (value/highest_value)*100

In this case the opacity is proportional to the value, rather than being equally spaced. In other words, if your values were 1, 2 and 10, in this case 1 and 2 would both be much less opaque than 10.

If you can get the highest value in the list, then you can just iterate over all of the values in the list replacing "value" and "highest_value" with the actual numbers each time.

Things to watch out for:

- You may have to force floating point division by multiplying highest_value by 1.0
- You may also have to convert the list values from strings into integers or floats